# Find customers who spent at least 10% more in 2019 than in 2018

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has 4 columns: branch_name,customer_id, order_value,purchase_date.

```
"london-branch", 422, "12","01-01-2019"
"manchester", 133, "33","01-04-2019"
"london", 422, "55","01-04-2019"
"newyork", 1223, "11","01-04-2019"
```

Want to find out how many customers spent more than 10% in 2019 than their total amount spent across 2018.

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE AS LastYr 

Select customer_id,order_value from order_table where purchase_date between '01-01-2018' AND '31-12-2018';
```

This will create table for 2018

Then

```
CREATE TABLE AS NewYear

Select customer_id,order_value from order_table where purchase_date between '01-01-2019' AND '31-12-2019';
```

Then am struggling to join the tables and find the difference.

Comment: You should include your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Which database are you using? You tagged MySQL and sqlite.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: What have you tries so far???

Comment: All you did up there is just create table, and do a simple select.  I don't see the part that you're struggling.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and conditional `SUM`s in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) IN (2018, 2019)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(purchase_date) = 2019 THEN order_value ELSE 0 END)
    > 1.1 * SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(purchase_date) = 2018 THEN order_value ELSE 0 END)
```

Note: this assumes that you are storing dates using the relevant datatype, not as strings.

Comment: @codeisfun1234: this means that they spent 10% more in 2019 than they did in 2018 (ie 1.1 times more).